# How to remove configuration setting on Hbase?

Tags: hbase

Currently I have a table with settings that look like this:

```
hbase(main):020:0> describe 'my_table'
Table my_table is ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                      
hdfs_storage_metadata, {CONFIGURATION => {'kafka.notification.broker' => 'kafka:6667,kafka1:6667,kafka2:6667', 'kafka.notification.health.topic
' => 'Kafka-topic', 'kafka.some.topic' => 'some-coprocessor'}}                                                                                                                  
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                 
{NAME => 'm', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLO
CKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1'}
```

However, I am trying to enable cross-cluster replication and am getting an error because my configuration settings are not the same for these tables. I need to remove the `CONFIGURATION` setting, but I cannot find a method with which to do it. I have looked at the documentation and have tried

```
alter 'my_table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset',NAME => 'CONFIGURATION'
```

But I get that `CONFIGURATION` cannot be found. From the [hbase-shell](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-shell/src/main/ruby/shell/commands/alter.rb) documentation, I tried

```
alter 'my_table', METHOD => 'table_conf_unset',NAME => 'CONFIGURATION'
```

But got that `table_conf_unset` could not be found. Is this something I can even do? I am not sure what other methods are possible.

I am running hbase version `1.1.2.2.6.0.3-8`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to unset each configuration separately like this:-

```
alter 'my_table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset', NAME => 'kafka.notification.broker'
alter 'my_table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset', NAME => 'kafka.notification.health.topic'
alter 'my_table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset', NAME => 'kafka.some.topic'
```

Comment: With that I get `Could not find attribute: kafka.notification.broker`.